# AWS Beanstalk and grails 2.3.7 war

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Since the app's upgrade to grails 2.3.7, the following pb appears when the war is deployed on EBS:

```
ERROR [GrailsContextLoader] - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 6 more
2014-03-15 13:46:21,912 ERROR [GrailsContextLoader] - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'validationQueryTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Bean property 'validationQueryTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

I've followed the doc recommandation regarding the datasource properties and there was no problem until this new deployment:

```
production {
  dataSource {
            pooled = true
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://*************:3306/***********?autoReconnect=true"
            username = "***********"
            password = "***********"
            logSql = false
            properties {
                maxActive = 10000
                maxIdle = 25
                minIdle = 5
                initialSize = 10
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                testOnBorrow = true
                testOnReturn = false
                testWhileIdle = true
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 600
            }
        }
}
```

Also trie with grails default values (set up when a new app is created) :

```
 properties {
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = 5
                maxActive = 50
                minIdle = 5
                maxIdle = 25
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 10 * 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false
                jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
                defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

A tested solution (can be interpreted as a workaround): **EBS tomcat 7 instance version is 7.0.27 by default on EBS, and grails last version is shipped with tomcat 7.0.52.** 
Then, there was a conflict with spring bean initialization context upon tomcat7's beanstalk instance. The weird thing for me it's that the validationTimeout  bean was impacted by that at first sight (see debug above).

I've upgraded the EBS with tomcat 7.0.47 (available from amzn-updates yum repository) which is compatible with grails 2.3.7. It brings, among others features, the use of the JSR-356 Java WebSocket 1.0 implementation which requires Java 7.

Hope that AWS team could follow posts like that to keep in touch which grails community and propose upgrade accordingly (a lot of grails projects are deployed on EBS by the way).